# What do I need to know when choosing a dedicated power supply?

Tags: power-supply

[This question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/26/68) asks about what you'd need to know to power a Pi from a non-dedicated power source.

It also links to the [Quick Start Guide](http://www.raspberrypi.org/quick-start-guide), which says:

> Micro USB power supply – make sure you use a good quality one, capable
>   of providing at least 700mA at 5V. Do not attempt to power your
>   Raspberry Pi by plugging it into a computer or a hub.

Are there any available lists online of power supplies that meet this specification?

Are there any sites with reviews indicating which manufacturers are more reputable? (Does it matter?)

Is there anything else I should know when choosing a power supply?

I'd like to know whether I can just buy the cheapest power supply I find (that provides 700mA), or whether I need to shop more carefully.

Answer (score 11):

It has been noted elsewhere that some power supplies (especially phone chargers) are faulty or poorly manufactured. You cannot really check this without taking it apart and using a multimeter, but you should take it into account when buying one, probably stay away from the cheapest.

Comment: http://www.arcfn.com/2012/05/apple-iphone-charger-teardown-quality.html

Answer (score 10):

I recommend buying a USB charger from a reputable retailer. Most decent chargers will be able to supply 1A.

You may already have one, as they are supplied with most new phones and tablets. As well as the charger, you will need a USB cable.

I am using my Kindle charger, as it is rated at 800mA and has the correct USB cable.

Answer (score 6):

When I had the chance to order my RPi from RS, I took the easy option and ordered the power supply they listed/offered at the same time, on the (possibly naive) assumption that this would be a suitable unit to use.

I would assume that Farnell would take the same sort of opportunity to flog you some extras.

I've not had a problem that I can identify as being the fault of the power supply so far.

Answer (score 2):

I very strongly recommend the [Pi Hut's Raspberry Pi Power supply](https://thepihut.com/collections/raspberry-pi-power-supplies/products/eu-micro-usb-power-supply-for-the-raspberry-pi).

I use it myself and it powers a Pi 3 running at 100% CPU usage with USB devices connected, absolutely no problem. It is specifically designed for powering the Pi, so it is your best bet. Nevertheless you can get away with something like a high quality tablet charger, as it will be able to supply the current.

Answer (score 1):

I have had good luck with a Cana power supply.  I don't know which model you're using these days (it's almost 5 years since you asked your question).  The [Cana Raspberry Pi 3](https://www.canakit.com/raspberry-pi-adapter-power-supply-2-5a.html) works with models up to the Pi 3. It's also highly rated by others on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MARDJZ4).

Here are the [power specs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs) from the Raspberry Pi website.