# Powering the PI over micro USB with a dumb (PC) power supply?

Tags: usb, power-supply

This is related to some existing questions (eg [Powering without using the micro USB](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/246/powering-without-using-the-micro-usb)), but they don't make clear one specific part. I want to power a Pi from a PC power supply's 5v rail, but I'll do so by making a custom cable with a microUSB end.

My question is if this will work, or if the Pi requires an actual USB power / current negotiation when being powered from microUSB, as opposed to via the GPIO pins. (It's much easier for my setup to hack the microUSB cable into the Pi, than to mess with the GPIOs)

Comment: There is a Raspberry Pi project called PiClock which uses a Raspberry Pi with a monitor to display an analogue clock with other information. In that project the person tapped into the display power with an inverter to get the necessary 5v power. They also noted that you need to have at least 2amps available. https://hackaday.io/project/6184-piclock-a-raspberry-pi-clock-weather-display#j-discussions-title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, plus an atx power supply is extremely "clean". Using the USB input circuit is way safer than putting power into the GPIO as that would be bypassing the polyfuse.