# Is there any reason why a powered USB hub that provides 700mA couldn't power a RP?

Tags: power-supply, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Powering from a non-dedicated power source](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26/powering-from-a-non-dedicated-power-source)

The [Quick Start Guide](http://www.raspberrypi.org/quick-start-guide) says:

> Micro USB power supply – make sure you use a good quality one, capable
>   of providing at least 700mA at 5V. Do not attempt to power your
>   Raspberry Pi by plugging it into a computer or a hub.

If I can find a powered USB hub that specifies it will provide at least 700mA, is there any reason why it shouldn't be used as the power supply?

Comment: Wow, 2 hours into a site and we already have duplicates :D

Comment: Ha, I saw that, but thought it was asking something else for some reason... oh well, duplicates are still good for searchability! Have joined you in voting to close :-)